# Why does the module variable exist when I import a library, but not in my code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running this code in Node JS v20. In `jquery.js`, what is this `module` *variable* and what created it? Why does it exist in `jquery.js` but not in `index.js`?

#### My `index.js`

```js
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
export {}

globalThis.window = {};
globalThis.document = {};

console.log(`globalThis.module`, globalThis.module); // undefined
console.log(`global.module`, global.module); // undefined
console.log(`window.module`, window.module); // undefined
try {
  console.log(`module`, module);
} catch (ex) {
  console.log(ex); // ReferenceError: module is not defined
}

const dynamicImport = await import('jquery');
```

#### My modified version of `node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js`

```js
/*!
 * jQuery JavaScript Library v3.7.1
 * https://jquery.com/
 *
 * Copyright OpenJS Foundation and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license
 * https://jquery.org/license
 *
 * Date: 2023-08-28T13:37Z
 */
( function( global, factory ) {

    "use strict";

    // logs added by me
    console.log(`globalThis.module`, globalThis.module); // undefined
    console.log(`global.module`, global.module); // undefined
    console.log(`window.module`, window.module); // undefined
    console.log(`module`, module); /*
module {
  id: 'projA\\node_modules\\jquery\\dist\\jquery.js',      
  path: 'projA\\node_modules\\jquery\\dist',
  exports: {},
  filename: 'projA\\node_modules\\jquery\\dist\\jquery.js',
  loaded: false,
  children: [],
  paths: [
    'projA\\node_modules\\jquery\\dist\\node_modules',     
    'projA\\node_modules\\jquery\\node_modules',
    'projA\\node_modules',
    'projAParent\\node_modules',
    'projAGrandparent\\node_modules'
  ]
}
    */
    console.log('typeof module === "object"', typeof module === "object");
    console.log(`typeof module.exports === "object"`, typeof module.exports === "object");

    if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" ) {
        module.exports = global.document ?
            factory( global, true ) :
            function( w ) {
                if ( !w.document ) {
                    throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
                }
                return factory( w );
            };
    } else {
        factory( global );
    }
} )( typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this, function( window, noGlobal ) {

"use strict";


  // everything else deleted by me


return jQuery;
} );
```

#### My `package.json`

```json
{
  // ...
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm run exec && jasmine",
    "exec": "node index.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^5.1.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.25",
    "@types/jsdom": "^21.1.4",
    "eslint": "^8.52.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine": "^5.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@prettier/sync": "^0.3.0",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "jsdom": "^22.1.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `package.json` has `"type": "module"`, so your code is interpreted as an ES6 module and *not* a CommonJS module. Therefore, the `module` symbol is not defined, as it would be in a CommonJS module.

Comment: That's also why your `export` statement doesn't throw a syntax error.

Comment: @Pointy okay, so `jquery` is a CommonJS module? How does it have this variable?

Comment: When node "makes" a CommonJS module from a source file, it effectively wraps it in a scope (a function I think, but whatever) and injects the `module` symbol.

Comment: I see. Thank you.